# Android how to change data recieved in spinner from array to recieve from object

Tags: java, android, spinner

My spinners receives data from `strings.xml` but i want to change the way of receiving data to get it from objects. I got class Team and name. I want to display the name in spinner. Can you help me? my code of class, object and spinner:

```
public class DruzynyStatActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public class Team {
        public String name;
        public String shoots;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_druzyny_stat);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_druzyny_stat, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void cracovia(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CracoviaActivity.class);
        Team cracovia = new Team();
        cracovia.name = "Cracovia";
        String name = cracovia.name;
        intent.putExtra("teamName", name);
        cracovia.shoots = "STRZAŁY: 10";
        String shoots = cracovia.shoots;
        intent.putExtra("shoots", shoots);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

and Spinners code:

```
public class PorownanieActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner spinner1;
    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_porownanie);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.ZESPOŁY, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.ZESPOŁY, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    }
}
```

Comment: See how to use custom adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your ArrayAdapter from the objects and set it to the Spinner.
You should have a look on the adapter constructor , You can write like this-

```
     String list[] = new String[]{"string1","string2"};
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can create adapter from any type of the Object , you should have a look on the constructors for the adapters.
         For more customization and object lists you can extend the BaseAapter and ArrayAdapter Classes also.